# How to add code to my post?

Tags: stack-overflow, support

I posted a question skipping my code. If one asks to post it, how can I add it to the question? Or I have to add it as a comment?

Comment: Just `edit` your post and add code to it

Comment: click Edit your post and made a changes

Comment: It's worth noting you should always include your (possibly simplified example) code in a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click "edit" under the tags in your post. It will bring up the edit page.